# Twitter List twitter4j

Tags: java, android, list, twitter

Hello i want to display a user timeline in a list with twitter4j, because im new to java i just don't know how to do that. I searched the web but couldn't find anything usefull. So my question is: does someone know how to display a user timeline in a list in android?

Answer (score 3):

twitter4j-core-2.2.6

```
Twitter tw = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

// some userlist
UserList userList = tw.getUserLists("screen name", -1).get(0);
System.out.println(userList.getName());

int listId = userList.getId();
ResponseList<Status> userListStatuses = tw.getUserListStatuses(listId, new Paging(1));

for (Status status : userListStatuses) {
    System.out.println(status.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the **[twitter4j Code Examples](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html)**

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getFriendsTimeline();
    System.out.println("Showing friends timeline.");
    for (Status status : statuses) {
        System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":" +
                           status.getText());
    }
```

Please check official document and code example for twitter4j

Comment: But how to use it? does i need to set it on a button function or what? Or have a to create a xml layout?

Comment: as per your requirement you can set above code , for create xml layout and listview implementation google it out , there is plenty of code example for listview

Comment: Ok but where i specify wich user timeline i display?

Comment: I think you want to show the feeds as a list. If so, then use a ListView & Adapter to show the tweets.